# Is it possible to deploy only reports which were changed using RS.exe?

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, rs.exe

Assuming I have 20 rdl files and I modified just one, is it possible in the deploy process to overwrite just this file instead the whole 20 in the SSRS server using RS.exe and VB.NET file?

Comment: How do you deploy your reports? You can edit and publish a report from report builder, deploy from SSDT a selected report, or upload the RDL to server

Comment: I'm doing it using RS.exe

Comment: Check this site http://source.technology/automated-ssrs-deployments-using-rs-exe. You need to modify the script to get only the rdl files modified in some specific date/time (saving the project modifies only changed rdl files)

Comment: The question if it's possible to modify the script to check only for mortified rlds..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer from SQL COMMUNITY EXPERT, rs.exe can only deploy the specified rdl file, but cannot automatically find and deploy the modified rdl file